# Rendering extra data with Mongoose results in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Say I have a function which finds all open bets in a collection:

```
app.get('/profile/bet-history', function(req, res, next){
        var user = req.user;
        if(user){
            Bet.find({$query : {"username" : user.username, "settled":false, "paired" : true}, $orderby : {_id : -1}})
                .then(function(doc){
                    res.render('profile/bet-history', {bets: doc, user: req.user}); 
            });
        }else{
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });
```

And I have a Handlebars template which renders the above `bets` and `user` data:

```
<tbody>
    {{#if bets}}
        {{#each bets}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{date this.createdAt}}</td>
                <td>{{this.market}}({{this.bet}})</td>
                <td>{{this.stake}}</td>
                <td>{{this.odds}}</td>
                <td>{{render the potential returns here}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>You have no matched bets. Please come back later.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}        
</tbody>
```

I want to perform a quick "potential returns" calculation on each individual result returned from `.find()` by calling some function `calcReturns()` which takes in the returned bet and multiplies the stake by the odds and then rendering that result of the function with the data returned by the `.find()` call, which is rendered in an `{{#each}}` partial. A key requirement is I want to use a function in an external .js file and I don't want to have to use another field in the Mongo database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on jervtub's answer, in order to use an external JS function, here's the final solution:
**GET Request**

```
var updates = require('./update.js');

app.get('/profile/bet-history', function(req, res, next){
        var user = req.user;
        if(user){
            Bet.find({$query : {"username" : user.username, "settled":false, "paired" : true}, $orderby : {_id : -1}})
                .then(function(doc){
                    // Add the potential_returns for our render object here
                    doc.forEach(function(x) {
                        updates.calcReturns(x);
                    })
                    res.render('profile/bet-history', {bets: doc, user: req.user}); 
            });
        }else{
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
});
```

**Update.js File**

```
module.exports = {
    calcReturns : function(x){
        if(x.bet == "Back"){
            x.potential_returns = x.stake * x.odds + x.stake;
        }else{
            x.potential_returns = x.stake * 2;
        }
    }
};
```

**Handlebars Template**

```
<tbody>
    {{#if bets}}
        {{#each bets}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{date this.createdAt}}</td>
                <td>{{this.market}}({{this.bet}})</td>
                <td>{{this.stake}}</td>
                <td>{{this.odds}}</td>
                <td>{{this.potential_returns}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>You have no matched bets. Please come back later.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}        
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the potential returns locally after the bets have been retrieved from the database.

```
app.get('/profile/bet-history', function(req, res, next){
        var user = req.user;
        if(user){
            Bet.find({$query : {"username" : user.username, "settled":false, "paired" : true}, $orderby : {_id : -1}})
                .then(function(doc){
                    // Add the potential_returns for our render object here
                    doc.forEach(function(x) {
                        // Calculate the potential returns
                        x.potential_returns = x.bet * x.odds
                    })
                    res.render('profile/bet-history', {bets: doc, user: req.user}); 
            });
        }else{
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });
```

`potential_returns` can be add to the `<tr>` in the same way as the other properties of `doc`

```
<tbody>
    {{#if bets}}
        {{#each bets}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{date this.createdAt}}</td>
                <td>{{this.market}}({{this.bet}})</td>
                <td>{{this.stake}}</td>
                <td>{{this.odds}}</td>
                <td>{{this.potential_returns}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>You have no matched bets. Please come back later.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {{/if}}        
</tbody>
```

Comment: Great suggestion jervtub! This works perfectly for me! I've used your idea and expanded a little by creating an external function that gets called inside the doc.forEach() call in order to meet that final requirement. Thank you.